# How to get custom context into haystack index template

Tags: django, django-haystack

How can I get context generated by my custom context processors to be available in the haystack index template?

(I mean: the template file that haystack reads when you do `./manage.py rebuild_index`)

I can load my custom filters with an explicit `{% load %}` template tag, but I can't see how to get the custom context loaded.   When I try to use it, it behaves as if the custom context is not defined.

I need it because the searchable (string) representation of some of the fields of the objects requires a function to generate it (the field is effectively an enum, but the user wants to search for the full text string of the value in that field).

Comment: You'll need to show some details. Context processors are automatically available in any template (as long as is rendered via a RequestContext).

Comment: But the haystack index template is not "rendered" in any usual sense.   Haystack uses it to generate it's input for searching, AIUI.   This is definitely a django-haystack specific question.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Can you show your context processor? Why don't you use a template tag instead of context processor function?

Comment: @GreenAsJade In response to your second comment: So there is no actual request involved hence custom context is not available as the loader can't use the `RequestContext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was confused by your use of "index template" - as I understand it, you're taking about the template used to construct the search document indexed by Haystack.

As you note, there is no request involved when that is rendered, so you can't use a RequestContext. That should really be a clue that context processors are not the right solution: you should be using template tags and filters instead.

Comment: Makes sense actually - I may have been abusing the custom context processor in the first place, now that I think about it: given that it doesn't need to know anything about an object to give it's answer, it's not really context!   It's just stuff that a custom tag could bring.